# Manipulate javascript array object if same data retrieved (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

so i am working on a module that will allow the user to click vendors. There will be more than 1 item.

So everytime user click on the vendor of a particular item, i will add the vendor name and price into a javascript array.

Assume after the user has chosen all the vendors, the vendor array will consist of

```
vm.vendor = [
    {checked:true, name : "Vendor 1", price: 1},
    {checked:true, name : "Vendor 2", price: 2},
    {checked:true, name : "Vendor 2", price: 3},
]
```

I want to list down the vendor total purchase. So i am thinking to ng-repeat the vm.vendor and then list down the vendor name and total price.

However, on above case, it will list down vendor 2, 2 times. How can i achieve

```
vendor 1 => total price : 1,
vendor 2 => total price : 5
```

how can i manipulate the array when the user is going to add another vendor that already exists in the array?

here is my code that enable the user to add the vendor to new array

```
function chooseVendor(item, vendor, index) {
vm.vendor = [];

for(var i = 0; i < vm.request_area.length; i++){
  for(var x = 0; x < vm.request_area[i].details.length; x++){
    for(var y = 0; y < vm.request_area[i].details[x].vendor_list.length; y++){
        if(vm.request_area[i].details[x].vendor_list[y].checked == true){
            vm.vendor.push(
                vm.request_area[i].details[x].vendor_list[y]
            )
        }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a check to see if the vendor is in the list already just before your push function. If it is, add the price instead of pushing a new object. Also you should use an id or key to reference them by to avoid looping through in the last loop.

```
function chooseVendor(item, vendor, index) {
    vm.vendor = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < vm.request_area.length; i++){

        for(var x = 0; x < vm.request_area[i].details.length; x++){

            var vendor_list = vm.request_area[i].details[x].vendor_list;

            for(var y = 0; y < vendor_list.length; y++){

                var vendor = vm.request_area[i].details[x].vendor_list[y];

                if(vendor.checked == true){
                    var name = vendor.name;
                    var existing = vendor_list.filter(function(vendor){
                        return vendor.name == name;  //could also use an id which would probably be better
                    });

                    if(!existing){
                        //if you know the index of the vendor in the
                        //vm.vendor array, you can access directly without
                        //this loop
                        for(var z = 0; z < vm.vendor.length; z++){
                            var this_vendor = vm.vendor[z];
                            if(this_vendor.name == name) this.vendor.price += vendor.price;
                        }
                    } else {
                        vm.vendor.push(vendor)
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```